# file_get_contents or fopen for reading several MB of php://input?

Tags: php, performance, fopen, file-get-contents

This might seem to be  a repeated question, but it is not: I receive several megabytes of data via php:/input (1-500mb) that I have to save in a file. Is more perfomance-wise (server load, speed) using :

```
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents('php://input'))
```

OR

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "r");
$temp = tmpfile();
$realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
fclose($input);

$target = fopen($filename, "w");
fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
fclose($target);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a shorter version still: [`copy`](http://php.net/copy)

```
  copy("php://input", $filename);
```

PHP already internally implements what your code does. (Not sure it would make a measurable difference). Albeit I'm uncertain why you'd create a temporary file first.

And if the input file is up to 500 MB, then the `file_get_contents` approach wouldn't work anyway, as it had to keep all that data in a string / memory.

Comment: Yes. `dd bs=1000000 count=500 < /dev/zero | php -r 'copy("php://stdin", "/dev/null");'` with `1,3 GB/s` -- Ha, okay. That's not a relevant performance check for your case though.

Comment: If you do what I think you are doing, the real constraint might be `post_max_size` in the `php.ini`